# Help with Forming a Diagram to Complete Problem

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I am having trouble forming a figure for this problem.

The tangents at points $A$, $B$, $C$ at the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ meet the lines $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ at $M,N,P$. Show that $M,N,P$ are collinear.

when I draw the tangent lines to points $A, B, C$ they just form a bigger triangle surrounding the circle. So I am having trouble picturing this diagram. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If $O$ is the circumcenter of $ABC$, the tangent to the circumcircle at $A$ is just the perpendicular to $OA$ through $A$.

[image]

By [Desargues' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem) the claim follows by proving that

> $ABC$ and its tangential triangle $A'B'C'$ are perspective.

On the other hand, the circumcenter of $ABC$ is the incenter of $A'B'C'$, hence the claim follows from the existence of the [Gergonne point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GergonnePoint.html). The [perspector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Perspector.html) of $ABC$ and $A'B'C'$ is also the [symmedian point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmedianPoint.html) of $ABC$.

Comment: can you denote M, N, and P in your diagram?

Comment: @rover2: done .

Comment: I have been trying to use power of a point. Is there a way to prove it using this method ? @Jack D'Aurizio

Comment: @rover2: maybe, but I do not see how. For sure, you cannot prove that three points are collinear by just computing their powers with respect to a circle.

Comment: that is true however, you can prove three points are collinear by showing that they lie on a radical axis. i am having trouble seeing how to use that method. @Jack D'Aurizio

Comment: @rover2: I am having troubles seeing *why* to use that method, since Desargues' theorem gives a straightforward solution.

Comment: i understand that, and i appreciate your solution. we just have not gone over Desargues' Theorem in class. we have been using radical axis and power of a point.

Comment: @rover2: learning math is not depending on your teacher's lessons. You are free to study and use also theorems that he/she has not mentioned yet - math is everything! :D